# 'origin' does not appear to be a remote repository

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I am trying to push some code into a new, fresh repo over at github. But I am getting the error below. I have done nothing strange, I always do the same steps, but this time, I see the error. I SO'd the error but none of the fixes work.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSlGg.png

The `git remote -v` command gives the following:

```
origin
upstream
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would happen if you accidentally put remote configurations in the system-level git config.  (I've seen this happen several times)

Run `git config --system --edit` and delete or comment out any `[remote ]` sections.